# How to create a System.Web.UI.Page object in a winform application?

Tags: asp.net, winforms

I have a class which inherits from the `System.Web.UI.Page` class, like `mysystem`.
When I try to create an instance of `mysystem` in a winform appplication it throws an `HttpException`:

> Session state can only be used when
>   enableSessionState is set to true,
>   either in a configuration file or in
>   the Page directive. Please also make
>   sure that
>   System.Web.SessionStateModule or a
>   custom session state module is
>   included in the
>   <configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules>
>   section in the application
>   configuration.

I then googled this problem and try to enable the session state, but all are not affected.

So, can anybody tell me how to solve this case?

Comment: Why are you attempting to use a class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` in a winforms application? If you can explain why, it might assist us in helping you solve this =)

Comment: this class is another dll which is come from my colleague.it runs well in asp.net application,but when it come to the winform ,it throw the exception like i posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` will attempt to utilise parts of the asp.net runtime when it's instantiated, so when it's used in a winforms application, it just won't work.

If there are methods that you need inside this class from another DLL, I'd suggest refactoring them into a separate class as:

- If you want to use them in a winforms app, they're almost certainly not specific to the page so should be shared anyway
- There's no good reason to try and use the asp.net runtime (other than, perhaps, caching) inside a winforms application